# What is the difference between "plunge" and "plunge down"?

Tags: vocabulary, american-english, learning

In the headline:

> Keanu Reeves plunges down the rabbit hole again in The Matrix Resurrections

what is the difference if I remove the "down" from "plunges down"?

P.S.: this headline was/is on NY Times but was changed through the day.

Comment: You can plunge _from_ a high point (fall rapidly), but you plunge _into_ or _down_ a hole.

Comment: The syntax of ***to plunge*** here is exactly the same as ***to go***. That's to say, just as you need the preposition in *Keanu Reeves **goes down** the rabbit hole*, you also need it in *Keanu Reeves **plunges down** the rabbit hole*.

Answer (score 1):

I think that it is notable to start by mentioning that one "plunges" a toilet, and that makes the following sentence a bit humorous!

> Keanu Reeves plunges the rabbit hole

In seriousness, there is a phrase **[down the rabbit hole](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/go+down+the+rabbit+hole)**, which means

> To enter into a situation… that is particularly strange… that becomes increasingly [strange] as it develops

To "[plunge down](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/plunge+down)" is

> To fall or plummet down something at a high… speed.

Putting these two (down the rabbit hole and plunge down) together, the sentence means that Keanu is "going down the rabbit hole" at what one can describe as a very fast speed.

If you remove the "down" from the original sentence, you

- (a) risk the reader thinking that Keanu is plunging the rabbit hole (like a toilet!), and
- (b) lose the idiomatic phrase "down the rabbit hole" and its meaning.